# Ubuntu 18.04 Network Connection cutting off randomly

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, internet, ethernet

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.

But now my network connection drops randomly. It happens when connected with Ethernet as well as with Wlan. I tried two different lan-cables, both of which worked fine before.

The ouput of `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` is:

```
Apr 28 15:48:49 i7 kernel: [  408.161936] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down
Apr 28 15:48:59 i7 kernel: [  418.117433] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
Apr 28 15:48:59 i7 kernel: [  418.117440] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
```

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f1)
00:1b.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #19 (rev f1)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM951/PM951 (rev 01)
```

`ifconfig -a`:

```
enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.93  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::5e03:8c96:eeaa:979a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 34:97:f6:8e:9c:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 106315  bytes 75284075 (75.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 696757  bytes 985446361 (985.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xf7300000-f7320000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 7792  bytes 7648787 (7.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7792  bytes 7648787 (7.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.94  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::3ea3:7811:db83:317  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 14:da:e9:f1:a6:6d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 438  bytes 139294 (139.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 77  bytes 12333 (12.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 14:da:e9:f1:a6:6d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=4.18.0-17-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.178.94 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7200000-f7203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 31
       serial: 34:97:f6:8e:9c:e2
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.8-4 ip=192.168.178.93 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:127 memory:f7300000-f731ffff
```

Can someone help me?

Edit #1:
Output of `ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:97:f6:8e:9c:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.93/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s31f6
       valid_lft 805451sec preferred_lft 805451sec
    inet6 fe80::5e03:8c96:eeaa:979a/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:da:e9:f1:a6:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.94/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 800956sec preferred_lft 800956sec
    inet6 fe80::3ea3:7811:db83:317/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Edit #2: Output of `ethtool -g enp0s31f6`

```
Ring parameters for enp0s31f6:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:     4096
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:     4096
Current hardware settings:
RX:     256
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:     256
```

Edit #3: [deleted]

Edit #4: So I just ran the Ubuntu 19.04 Live USB Version. I also have the same problem there. Same message in `/var/log/kern.log`. 
Additionally I got the following message in `kern.log`: `Driver has suspect GRO implementation, TCP performance may be compromised.`

Edit #5:

So I found a workaround: I am now using an USB-Ethernet Adapter ( Router->Ethernet->Adapter->USB->PC ).

Further Information: What I figured since I initially described the problem is that the connection drops happen when I click on a link, open a new tab and start a websearch. So it might have something to do with starting a http request. But I don't know for sure. When downloading a big file I don't get the connection drops while downloading.

Edit #6: `kern.log` when disabling lan and only using wlan:

```
May  5 18:09:20 i7 kernel: [  108.077780] wlp2s0: AP 24:65:11:ad:a3:4a changed bandwidth, new config is 2462 MHz, width 1 (2462/0 MHz)
May  5 18:09:21 i7 kernel: [  108.897066] wlp2s0: AP 24:65:11:ad:a3:4a changed bandwidth, new config is 2462 MHz, width 2 (2452/0 MHz)
May  5 18:09:22 i7 kernel: [  109.920896] wlp2s0: AP 24:65:11:ad:a3:4a changed bandwidth, new config is 2462 MHz, width 1 (2462/0 MHz)
May  5 18:09:32 i7 kernel: [  120.161068] wlp2s0: AP 24:65:11:ad:a3:4a changed bandwidth, new config is 2462 MHz, width 2 (2452/0 MHz)
May  5 18:09:42 i7 kernel: [  130.271599] rtlwifi: AP off, try to reconnect now
May  5 18:09:42 i7 kernel: [  130.271653] wlp2s0: Connection to AP 24:65:11:ad:a3:4a lost
May  5 18:09:43 i7 kernel: [  131.417327] wlp2s0: authenticate with 24:65:11:ad:a3:4a
May  5 18:09:43 i7 kernel: [  131.437037] wlp2s0: send auth to 24:65:11:ad:a3:4a (try 1/3)
May  5 18:09:43 i7 kernel: [  131.440142] wlp2s0: authenticated
May  5 18:09:43 i7 kernel: [  131.444617] wlp2s0: associate with 24:65:11:ad:a3:4a (try 1/3)
May  5 18:09:43 i7 kernel: [  131.451848] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 24:65:11:ad:a3:4a (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
May  5 18:09:43 i7 kernel: [  131.452237] wlp2s0: associated
May  5 18:09:46 i7 kernel: [  133.985199] wlp2s0: AP 24:65:11:ad:a3:4a changed bandwidth, new config is 2462 MHz, width 1 (2462/0 MHz)
May  5 18:09:47 i7 kernel: [  134.906814] wlp2s0: AP 24:65:11:ad:a3:4a changed bandwidth, new config is 2462 MHz, width 2 (2452/0 MHz)
May  5 18:10:20 i7 kernel: [  168.085188] wlp2s0: AP 24:65:11:ad:a3:4a changed bandwidth, new config is 2462 MHz, width 1 (2462/0 MHz)
```

Edit #7: `ethtool -k enp0s31f6`

```
Features for enp0s31f6:                         
rx-checksumming: on                             
tx-checksumming: on                             
        tx-checksum-ipv4: off [fixed]           
        tx-checksum-ip-generic: on              
        tx-checksum-ipv6: off [fixed]           
        tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: off [fixed]       
        tx-checksum-sctp: off [fixed]           
scatter-gather: on                              
        tx-scatter-gather: on                   
        tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: off [fixed] 
tcp-segmentation-offload: off                   
        tx-tcp-segmentation: off [requested on] 
        tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off [fixed]    
        tx-tcp-mangleid-segmentation: off       
        tx-tcp6-segmentation: off [requested on]
udp-fragmentation-offload: off                  
generic-segmentation-offload: on                
generic-receive-offload: on                     
large-receive-offload: off [fixed]              
rx-vlan-offload: on                             
tx-vlan-offload: on                             
ntuple-filters: off [fixed]                     
receive-hashing: on                             
highdma: on [fixed]                             
rx-vlan-filter: off [fixed]                     
vlan-challenged: off [fixed]                    
tx-lockless: off [fixed]                        
netns-local: off [fixed]                        
tx-gso-robust: off [fixed]                      
tx-fcoe-segmentation: off [fixed]               
tx-gre-segmentation: off [fixed]                
tx-gre-csum-segmentation: off [fixed]           
tx-ipxip4-segmentation: off [fixed]             
tx-ipxip6-segmentation: off [fixed]             
tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: off [fixed]            
tx-udp_tnl-csum-segmentation: off [fixed]       
tx-gso-partial: off [fixed]                     
tx-sctp-segmentation: off [fixed]               
tx-esp-segmentation: off [fixed]                
tx-udp-segmentation: off [fixed]                
fcoe-mtu: off [fixed]                           
tx-nocache-copy: off                            
loopback: off [fixed]                           
rx-fcs: off                                     
rx-all: off                                     
tx-vlan-stag-hw-insert: off [fixed]             
rx-vlan-stag-hw-parse: off [fixed]              
rx-vlan-stag-filter: off [fixed]                
l2-fwd-offload: off [fixed]                     
hw-tc-offload: off [fixed]                      
esp-hw-offload: off [fixed]                     
esp-tx-csum-hw-offload: off [fixed]             
rx-udp_tunnel-port-offload: off [fixed]         
tls-hw-tx-offload: off [fixed]                  
rx-gro-hw: off [fixed]                          
tls-hw-record: off [fixed]
```

Comment: In looking at your data, it looks like a cabling problem. Please describe the cabling from the computer all the way to the router/modem. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema The computer is connected via a Cat-5 E Patch Cable directly to the router. It worked perfectly fine this way for the last 3 years. Only since Ubuntu 18.04 I am having the problems described.

Comment: I just noticed that you're having both wired and wireless issues. Have you **power cycled** the router by unplugging it from AC power?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to run the following command everytime after booting (replace INTERFACENAME with the actual name of the ethernet interface):

```
/usr/sbin/ethtool --change INTERFACENAME speed 100 duplex half autoneg off
```

I use this systemd service unit, to run the command upon startup:

```
[Unit]
Description=Ethernet Fix
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=PATH_TO_BASH_SCRIPT

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try **power cycling** your router by unplugging/wait 10 seconds/replugging it from AC power. Recheck the drop issues.

For the ethernet drop issue... although this is not the preferred solution, you can try it and see if it solves the problem...

In `terminal`, use the `nm-connection-editor`, set the "Link negotiation" to "manual/100Mb/full".

[image]

Comment: I tried both of your solutions. But the problem persists.

Comment: @user2740514 Let's check your BIOS version. `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Now go to the manufacturor's web site, with make/model go to the support area and check for BIOS update. Report back.

Comment: I did a BIOS update today. Problem persists.

Comment: @user2740514 try booting to a Ubuntu Live 19.04 DVD/USB and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @user2740514 status update please

Comment: See Edit #4, of my original post.

Comment: @user2740514 let me ask some real basic questions... what brand/make/model is this computer? Laptop or desktop? How old?

Comment: It is a self assembled Intel Core i7 6700K with an ASUS Z170 Pro Gaming Mainboard.

Comment: It is a desktop computer. Bought in 2016.

Comment: Please see Edit #5

Comment: @user2740514 still wireless problems?

Comment: Yes, still wireless problems. See Edit #6 for the logs. Also, I actually don't want to use the wireless connection, since I am using wireless headphones and they interfere with the the wlan signal. I just tried wlan as a fallback option since the connection of ethernet didn't work. Also don't worry I wasn't using my headphones and had them turned off while testing the wireless connection.

Comment: @user2740514 do you know what channel your wireless network is using? Is it set to auto, or a specific channel? Do you have wifi-analyser installed on your phone so you can see if other networks are interfering with the channel that  your network is using?

Comment: I actually don't want to debug that wlan connection. As I told you, I don't intend to use it anyway. I am now calling it quits, since the USB-Ethernet Adapter is working just fine. Thanks for your help.